# is it possible to merge/downmix stereo to mono without reencoding (m4a or opus)

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I need to convert stereo to mono files of m4a and opus extension.

ffmpeg -i input.m4a -ac 1 output.m4a : this will do job but will re-encode and change bit-rate... is there a way to merge without re-encoding(looseless) or to extract channels into separate files?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can use `channelsplit` filter:

```
ffmpeg -i stereo.m4a -filter_complex "[0:a]channelsplit=channel_layout=stereo[left][right]" -map "[left]" left.m4a -map "[right]" right.m4a
```

as described in: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation

You can also use pan filter described here: https://superuser.com/questions/601972/ffmpeg-isolate-one-audio-channel

It is an old post, but pan filter is still used.
Filter should only filter out stream, not re-encode.

Comment: I tried this and ended up with a two-channel result. I suppose it's "mono" in the sense that both channels are identical, but how would I get truly monophonic output?